# Facebook API: Post on friend wall

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post something on a users friends wall, without having to get all the friends first (So you can get the friend id)?

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Only if you know the friend id.. But what are you trying to do? Seems to me that at some point you are showing a friend so that the user actually knows who he/she is messaging, right?

Comment: I want to have a button called "Share this with your friend"... so it would be nice if you could get a list in the facebook api that displays all the friend, and then you can check the ones you would like to share the information to, and the just hit share..

Comment: Okay... Well, use the call you posted to get all your friends and store the identifiers in an array so that you can message them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this

```
-(IBAction)PostToBuddyWall
{

NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


[postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"LOL" forKey:@"name"];    
[postVariablesDictionary setObject:self.postTextView.text forKey:@"message"];


[objDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",friendId] andParams:postVariablesDictionary andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];

NSLog(@"message: %@",postVariablesDictionary);
[postVariablesDictionary release];

UIAlertView *facebookAlter=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Posted successfully on facebook" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil, nil];
[facebookAlter show];
[facebookAlter release]; 

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Really bad to show a success alert without even being sure it was indeed success. Use the FB delegate methods for this.

Comment: Thanks for response. However, With this approach, you must know that friends ID... I want to handle all that in the facebook popup api?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the friends of the logged in user by issuing a request to `me/friends`.
Then you can create a ui element that shows the list of friends and the user can select the ones he want to share with.

Then, after the user selected you simply post on their walls by issuing a POST to `FRIEND_ID/feed` ([Feed connection of the User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed)).
You'll need to have the `publish_stream` permissions which lets you: `Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends` (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)