# Selecting and posting to a Facebook Friend's wall from an iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Hackbook sample code below in an app. The method **getFriendsCallAPIDialogFeed** says (in the comments) that this method "get's the user's friends, allowing them to pick one and post on their wall"

```
    /*
 * Helper method to first get the user's friends then
 * pick one friend and post on their wall.
 */
- (void)getFriendsCallAPIDialogFeed {
    // Call the friends API first, then set up for targeted Feed Dialog
    currentAPICall = kAPIFriendsForDialogFeed;
    [self apiGraphFriends];
}
```

however in line     **currentAPICall = kAPIFriendsForDialogFeed;** it calls the request method below and then **kAPIFriendsForDialogFeed**.

The problem I'm having is that it picks a user's friend randomly. I need the user to be able to select a friend of their choice instead.

thanks for any help

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    [self hideActivityIndicator];
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && ([result count] > 0)) {
        result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    switch (currentAPICall) {

        case kAPIFriendsForDialogFeed:
        {
            NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey: @"data"];
            // Check that the user has friends
            if ([resultData count] > 0) {

                // Pick a random friend to post the feed to
                int randomNumber = arc4random() % [resultData count];
                [self apiDialogFeedFriend: 
                 [[resultData objectAtIndex: randomNumber] objectForKey: @"id"]];
            } else {
                [self showMessage:@"You do not have any friends to post to."];
            }
            break;
        }
```

this code populates a table with all friends, from which you can select. the selection only posts a message/request to their notifications and not to their walls - which is what I need.

```
        case kAPIGetAppUsersFriendsUsing:
    {
        NSMutableArray *friendsWithApp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        // Many results
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            [friendsWithApp addObjectsFromArray:result];
        } else if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
            [friendsWithApp addObject: [result stringValue]];
        }

        if ([friendsWithApp count] > 0) {
            [self apiDialogRequestsSendToUsers:friendsWithApp];

        } else {
            [self showMessage:@"None of your friends are using Whatto."];
        }

        [friendsWithApp release];
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `resultData` to populate a table and then move the posting code into the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self apiDialogFeedFriend: 
        [[resultData objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"id"]];
}
```

This SO question tells you how to post to a friend's wall: [Facebook API: Post on friend wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773030/facebook-api-post-on-friend-wall?rq=1)

Comment: If you want the user to be able to able to select a friend then you need to provide a way to select a friend... I don't use the Facebook API, but I know there is a specific function that does a wall post

Comment: that's correct, as the comments say "Helper method to first get the user's friends then pick one friend and post on their wall." it picks a friend randomly though.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a question that contains wall-posting code.