# Post to friends wall using iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook API: Post on friend wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773030/facebook-api-post-on-friend-wall)

I'm trying to post the message on a friends wall. But it doesn't work with my below code,

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [params setObject:@"Some text" forKey:@"user_message_prompt"];
 [params setObject:@"another text" forKey:@"action_links"];

 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"****FB ID here *****/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

I tried many ways to figure it out, but couldn't find the solution. Please let me know what I did wrong in my code. I need a quick help to resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I push messages to a friends Facebook wall:

In your .h file:

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "FBRequest.h"
#import "FBLoginButton.h"

....

Facebook* _facebook;
NSArray* _permissions;

...

@property (readonly) Facebook *facebook;
```

In your .m file:

```
@synthesize facebook = _facebook;
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
_permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",@"user_videos",@"publish_stream",@"offline_access",@"user_checkins",@"friends_checkins",@"email",@"user_location" , @"read_stream", @"read_friendlist",nil] retain];
_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];



SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
static NSString* kAppId = @"your app key";

NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"your title",@"text",@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facts!/id434894484?l=de&ls=1&mt=8",@"href", nil], nil];

NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"Title of the post", @"name",
                                    @"Caption of the post", @"caption",
                                    @"Some description", @"description",
                                    nil];

NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       kAppId, @"api_key",
                                       @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                       actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                       attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                       @"your friends id", @"to",
                                       nil];

[_facebook dialog: @"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

**One thing has to be clear. You can only post to a friends wall when he is really in your friendlist, otherwise it will not work. I tested the code on my profile and it works!**

Comment: Thanks for your reply . . I'm getting the same problem, The post is not reflecting in my friends FB page. I only replace the Api key and your friends id in your code. Please let me know what the problem here. My friend id : 100001609148507 and My App Id : 134171240076227. . I have given the following permissions : @"read_friendlists",@"publish_stream",@"read_stream" Please check in your end and give me a solution. Waiting for your reply. . Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ManojArunS, I added some more code for you. I tested it on my facebook profile. You can only post to a friends wall when he is in your friendlist. The code works for me. So please consider accepting it.

Comment: Hi Dooonot. Thanks for your reply again. I accept your answer . . I'm getting Below error in log : "FBConditionalLog: FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage permissions contains unexpected read permissions" Do you have any idea about this error. ?

Comment: Did you set the permissions as mentioned above? You could try to remove @read_stream...

Comment: Yes i did. . The follow line : facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId]; what does it mean. .? When i give the input and it gives as some warning and while executing i'm getting method calling error. . I'm struggling on this issue from morning. Please help me to solve. .

Comment: It initialies the facebook object from the .h file with your app id.

Comment: @doonot So useful,but can we schedule the post? Ex:Posting wishes message on friends birthday!!

Comment: No this cannot be done.

Comment: @doonot Are you sure that we can't achieve it under any cost?? because I have the requirement of posting on friends wall on his/her birthday!!